# Loop if Row is different from Row above, Pastes the row in different Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, spreadsheet

I'm pretty new to VBA and I'm having issues creating a code that looks through a table and if the first 3 row values are the same as the next row, then it will paste the row into a different worksheet.

Currently my table looks like (from column A to column D):

| Activity | Role | Country | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Senior | US | 2 |
| A | Exec | UK | 3 |
| A | Exec | UK | 1 |
| B | Staff | UK | 7 |
| B | Senior | UK | 3 |
| C | Manager | UK | 5 |
| C | Manager | Uk | 4 |
| C | Staff | US | 2 |

My finished table in a different worksheet should should look like:

| Activity | Role | Country | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Senior | US | 2 |
| A | Exec | UK | 4 |
| B | Staff | UK | 7 |
| B | Senior | UK | 3 |
| C | Manager | UK | 9 |
| C | Staff | US | 2 |

Currently this is the code I have

```
Sub FinalOutput()
Dim wip As Worksheet, opt As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range
Dim eRow As Long
Dim R As Range
Dim i As Long
eRow = 3
i = 3

Set wip = Sheets("WIP_Output")
Set opt = Sheets("Opt")
Set R = Sheets("WIP_Output").Range("A1:C1")

Do
If R.Offset(eRow).Value <> R.Offset(eRow - 1).Value Then
        R.Offset(eRow).Copy Destination:=opt.Range("A" & i)
        eRow = eRow + 1
        i = i + 1
        
    End If
eRow = eRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does a pivot table not achieve this?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I have another worksheet that also needs to be matched at the end, due to the many to many relationships and duplicate values in each column, I can't use the pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

`Range.Value` returns an array if the range contains more than one cell. Your line `R.Offset(eRow).Value <> R.Offset(eRow - 1).Value` is comparing two arrays, which is not possible with the `<>` operator, why you get a type mismatch error.

Instead, just compare all three individual values from columns A, B, C without collecting them into an array.

```
With R.Offset(eRow)
    If .Cells(1, 1).Value <> .Cells(0, 1).Value _
    Or .Cells(1, 2).Value <> .Cells(0, 2).Value _
    Or .Cells(1, 3).Value <> .Cells(0, 3).Value _
    Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If
End With
```

But from what you said in your post, the boolean is opposite from what you're actually attempting to do. You want to copy the rows from when all three values MATCH, not when they're different. So you want

```
With R.Offset(eRow)
    If .Cells(1, 1).Value = .Cells(0, 1).Value _
    And .Cells(1, 2).Value = .Cells(0, 2).Value _
    And .Cells(1, 3).Value = .Cells(0, 3).Value _
    Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If
End With
```

Edit: I should also mention, your loop has no ending condition and will run  until it errors at the end of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a dictionary possibly?  I think i can see what you want, fingers crossed.  You will need to add the microsoft scripting runtime reference for the dictionary.

This is what i have done so far, got to leave now, so the pasting bit will need the key separation, but this code takes table 1 from a2:d9 and pastes the results in G and H

```
Sub test()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim l As Long
Dim dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim strKey As String

Set r = Range("a2:d9")
a = r.Value

For l = 1 To UBound(a)

    strKey = a(l, 1) & "_" & a(l, 2) & "_" & a(l, 3)
    
    If Not dic.Exists(strKey) Then
        dic.Add strKey, a(l, 4)
    Else
        dic.Item(strKey) = dic.Item(strKey) + a(l, 4)
    End If
    
Next l

Range("g1").Resize(dic.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Keys())
Range("h1").Resize(dic.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Items())

End Sub
```